# Looking for a AWS service that can copy data between database tables (or between S3 and DB) AWS RDS and on-premises DB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking for an AWS service simply capable of

1) Reading data from a relational database (MSSQL and MySQL) which can be an AWS RDS instance or on-premises server.

2) Capable of reading data - CSV - from S3 as the input. This can also be used instead of option 1 above.

3) Capable of UPSERT (MERGE) in order to UPDATE the existing records on the target database. This is important, because we do not want to purge the data in the target table.

I looked into AWS Data Pipeline and AWS Glue, however especially I could not find anything on UPSERT support. I wonder if there is any service ready to use or should I implement something custom that I can run on Lambda for ex.

Answer (score 1):

I think DMS is the service you are looking for

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/index.html

> AWS Database Migration Service is a web service you can use to migrate
>   data from your database that is on-premises, on an Amazon Relational
>   Database Service (Amazon RDS) DB instance, or in a database on an
>   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance to a database on an
>   AWS service.

And here are the source and destination endpoints:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Endpoints.html

Comment: I have been looking into DMS documentation, but may be I missed however could see any note about UPSERT. Is it done automatically by DMS?

Comment: DMS works with a primary key. So the records missing will be inserted and the rest will be updated. Which is what UPCERT really is.